# Show that the closed ball around some point in a metric space is a closed set.

Tags: real-analysis

The closed ball is the set of $y$ around some $x$ such that $d(x,y) \leq r$ for some $r>0$ where $d(x,y)$ is a metric on the space containing $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Pick a point in the complement, and determine its distance to the ball, then look at an open ball of smaller radius.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in the closed ball
$\{y| d(x,y)\le r\}$ and some $z$ with $x_n\to z$.  You have $d(x_n, x)\le r$ for all $n$. What do you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $B = B [x; r]$.
Show that the complement of $B$ is open.

Be the $a \in \mathbb{R}^n-B = B^c=B_1$ and consider $\delta = d(a, x) - r$.

Then for any $y \in B_1$, $d(y,a)<\delta = d(a,x) - r$ (1)

and

$d(a,x) \le d(a,y) + d(y,x) $ (2) (triangle inequality).

So (1) + (2) gives us $d(y,x) < r$.

Therefore, $B$ is open.